# Jinja2 how to escape character '?' in html template file?

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I already put safe filter.
[image]
In my html output, I expected to receive
[image]
But I keep receiving this instead
[image]

Why it keeps happening? I am totally new. Please teach me how can I remove that %3F by replacing it with '?' character ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows, the question mark character is forbidden in file names, this is why the `url_for()` function encodes it. However you don't need to include this suffix at all in `url_for()`, it expects a real file path. You can put this suffix after the `url_for()` calling e.g.:

```
href="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/fonts/wolmart.woff') }}?png09e"
```

Comment: I should have had thought this trick. Tq very much. I really appreciate this discussion.